# Could md5 hash of a string be different one place to another?

Tags: php, md5, hash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will the MD5 cryptographic hash function output be same in all programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450983/will-the-md5-cryptographic-hash-function-output-be-same-in-all-programming-langua)

Hi,

I have a problem about md5 hashing. Users can upload profile picures on my project. I am md5 hashing usernames for profile picture name. But there is something interesting. I am hashing a value both with a test page on my server and md5 encrypt websites with same result. When I use this encryption for renaming image, it produces something different. It produces different value on image manipulation file.

Do you have any idea?

This is my check script:

```
<?php echo md5('funky'); ?>
```

It produces below code on my server and also on md5encrypter.com :

```
6b818a3a6bf1234ed24c940021922b63
```

But it produces on my image manipulation file below code. I dont know what it is:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Script for sql query. $userId comes from logged in userId:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE userId='$userId'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $username=$row['username'];
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450983/will-the-md5-cryptographic-hash-function-output-be-same-in-all-programming-langua/3451013#3451013

Comment: Ahmet could you add some code to go with your question?

Comment: This should not be closed, it's not really a dupe of that other question. Ahmet is simply hypothesising it's an MD5 problem, when it's actually that he's hashed an empty string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` is the MD5 hash of an empty string, so somewhere you have failed to fill your string with something more useful...

MD5 will always produce the same output for a given input, otherwise it's not MD5. What I did was simply google for the hash you got, and it turned up a lot of hits. If I didn't get a hit, I would have searched some of the reverse MD5 dictionaries which are around to see if that gave some clues.

As luck would have it, your hash is simply the result of `MD5('')`, is very common. It clearly indicates you tried to obtain something from your DB, failed, and hashed it anyway.

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't notice that until you mentioned it.

Comment: yes, I will expand to explain how I hit upon that!

Comment: Really? That means I am fighting for 'nothing' for over 12 hours. :S Thanks Paul, appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

make 100%  sure you are standardizing the input data everywhere as in `$enc_md5=md5(trim(strtolower($filename)));`

Often unintended whitespace or capitalization result in different MD5 hashes for what was assumed to be identical data.

Comment: +1 cause this is a great point, one that has tripped me up many times before.

Comment: problem was not because of it but I will use that from now on. Thank you