# Same binary produces different md5

Tags: php, node.js, character-encoding, cryptography, md5

Check this out:

I want to encode a string as binary and print it's md5. I have 2 code bases: node and php.

PHP:

```
<?php
$key="12ab";
$hex_key = pack('H*', $key);
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($hex_key); $i++) {
    echo ord(substr($hex_key, $i ,1))."\n";
}       
echo md5($hex_key)."\n";
```

Produces this output:

```
/code # php md5.php 
18
171
53e035069bdb4f08a666fb7d42f29b15
```

Node:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const key = "12ab";

let hex_key = "";

for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i += 2) {
    hex_key += String.fromCharCode( parseInt(key[i] + key[i+1], 16) );
}
for (var i = 0; i < hex_key.length; i++) {
    console.log(hex_key.charCodeAt(i));        
}
console.log( crypto.createHash('md5').update( hex_key).digest("hex");
```

Produces this output:

```
/code # node md5.js
18
171
3f83d1a9a01e19e1a85665394f0f5a09
```

You can see the binary has the same code, and is in the same order.
How is it possible to not have the same md5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450983/will-the-md5-cryptographic-hash-function-output-be-same-in-all-programming-langu

Comment: There is one of two possibilities: 1. MD5 is broken in one of the implementations. 2. You are not supplying the same input. I would bet on #2, debug and insure the values are supplied in the expected formats and the outputs are being displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string should be switched to binary buffer before sending it to md5

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const key = "12ab";

let hex_key = "";

for (let i = 0; i < key.length; i += 2) {
    hex_key += String.fromCharCode( parseInt(key[i] + key[i+1], 16) );
}
var str = ""
console.log('length ' + hex_key.length);
for (var i = 0; i < hex_key.length; i++) {
    console.log(hex_key.charCodeAt(i));
}
console.log( crypto.createHash('md5').update(new Buffer(hex_key, "binary")).digest("hex"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't store binary data in a string. It rarely works. Use the appropriate containers such as a `Buffer`:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const key = "12ab";

console.log(crypto.createHash('md5').update(new Buffer(key, "hex")).digest("hex"));
```